# Php Mongodb $and Query Eror

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$veri=array();
```

!Sometimes `$veri` array is empty, or in some mongo oblect id.

```
$urun = $c->find(array('_id' => array('$nin' => $veri)))->limit(50); /// İts Work
$urun = $c->find(array('_id' => array('$nin' => $veri)),'cin'=>2)->limit(50); /// Not Work
```

I want this query not in $veri id AND cin =2 
What is the true query? Thanks

Comment: Show some data that you do expect to match and you will get some input on what the correct query arguments are.

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error
your query `$urun = $c->find(array('_id' => array('$nin' => $veri)),'cin'=>2)->limit(50);`
let's have a look whats inside `find(...)` :

```
array('_id' => array('$nin' => $veri)),'cin'=>2
```

you didn't close your array
you should change it to

```
$c->find(array('_id' => array('$nin' => $veri),'cin'=>2))->limit(50);
```